# Jenkins on Linux Server Behind VPN Not Connecting to GitHub Webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, vpn, github-webhook

I'm setting up continuous integration of a GitHub repository to automatically be pulled down by Jenkins onto a Linux server that is behind my company VPN that I do not control.

I have setup an Private SSH Key as both Jenkins Credentials and GitHub Deploy Key. I keep getting authenticating errors when Jenkins tries to connect to the SSH Repository URL. Is the VPN causing GitHub to not be able to POST to the server? Or am I missing something else?

ERROR MESSAGE:
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@github.com:MyOrganization/MyRepository.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: The webhook settings page can help you verify whether the payload was delivered. The error message indicates an authentication issue. https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Comment: Don't see where this is related to web hooks - although you won't have success with non-public IP addresses here as well.